# Go to a specific URL anchor, while passing variables

Tags: jquery

I have some `jQuery` that sends the user to another URL and passes 3 params:

```
window.open('http://staging.mysite.com/#initial-input?param1=' + p1 + '&param2=' + p2 + '&param3=' + p3, '_blank');
```

The params send just fine, but I would like the page to move down to the `initial-input` anchor. If I put the following in my address bar and hit ENTER it works fine:

`http://staging.mysite.com/#initial-input`

If I scroll up and hit `F5` or `ctrl + F5`, it doesn't go to the `#initial-input` anchor.

Also, if I have my variables attched to the URL like I do above, it doesn't go to the `#initial-input` anchor in any of the mentioned situations.

How can I send the user to my URL, to the `#initial-input` anchor, and pass variables and have it work consistently?

Comment: I think you should use `http://staging.mysite.com/?param1=p1&param2=p2#initial-input` , if the parameters are for your backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash (anchor) should be after any url parameters:

```
http://staging.mysite.com/?param1=foo&param2=bar#initial-input
```